# PHP How do I create an if statement using only preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to append a URL if necessary, and skip over it when not necessary. The think is, I'm learning php right now and I would like to use regular expressions as much as possible. would it be possible to make this code more concise using preg_match? Example:

```
<?php
$facebook_url = str_replace("facebook.org","facebook.com", trim($_REQUEST['facebook_url']));

$position = strpos($facebook_url, "facebook.com");

if ($position === false) {
  $facebook_url = "http://www.facebook.com/" . $facebook_url;
}

?>
```

But using:

```
    if  (!preg_match("/^(http:///www.facebook.com | facebook.com)/i"), $facebook_url)) {
    $facebook_url = "http://www.facebook.com/" . $facebook_url;     
}
```

I feel like that should work the way I understand php syntax, but something isn't working right. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Concise code is much less useful than readable code. Sorry, but i HAVE to make this disclaimer.

Comment: Change your regex to `^(http:\/\/www.facebook.com|facebook.com)`, without spaces and escape `\\`

Comment: `preg_replace(/(facebook\.com)(\/i)?/, $facebook_url, "facebook.com/$facebook_url");` 

This should append the url only if the the regex matches so in effect it's what you're looking for... I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to use regex "as much as possible" as opposed to as much as is needed, which should be very little.  In your case the original code is much faster, and you can still do it with less code:

```
if (stripos($facebook_url, "facebook.com") === false) {
```

Your regex would require a space after the `.com` or before the `facebook` in the alternation.  Space matters in regex.